# R / Dygraphs hex color codes

Tags: r, colors, dygraphs

When calling **dyOptions(colors...** in R, using hex colour codes does not seem to work (renders plot as black)

Whereas e.g. `dyOptions(colors = c("red","blue"))` works fine.

I have a series of custom colours I have defined in hex, stored as a couple of different vectors (a vector of different shades of blue and vector of other colours). Indexing into that vector does not work, but neither does using an example hex colour in character form (e.g. color = "#094FA4FF")

e.g.

```
a<-c(1,3,4,8,10)

b<-c(2.6,3.7,2.1,4.4,9.9)

timeindex<-as.POSIXct(c("2015-07-27 04:05:29.188","2015-07-27 06:14:59.036","2015-07-27 06:24:58.556","2015-07-27 07:15:58.977","2015-07-27 07:18:44.621"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")


dyMultiColumn <- function(dygraph) {

  dyPlotter(dygraph = dygraph,

            name = "MultiColumn",

            path = system.file("plugins/multicolumn.js",

                               package = "dygraphs"))
}


my_dygraph_multibar<-function(input.df, ts.vec){

  plot.df<-xts(input.df, order.by = as.POSIXct(ts.vec)) 

  dygraph(plot.df) %>%

    dyRangeSelector() %>% 

    dyMultiColumn() %>%

    dyOptions(colors = c("red","blue")) 

}
```

Calling the chart thus:

```
my_dygraph_multibar(input.df=cbind(a,b), ts.vec=timeindex)
```

This works fine, but only with `dyOptions(colors = c("red", "blue"))`
If I change to either

`dyOptions(colors = c("#094FA4FF","#006EC1FF"))`   or
`dyOptions(colors = my_palette[1:2])`

It fails to render in colour. What am I doing wrong? I use the hex colour palettes for other graphics (almost entirely base_R stuff) so I am working on the assumption that the issue is not in my hex codes...

Comment: I was mistaken. The problem lies in the use of `dyMultiColumn`...

Answer (score 0):

The plugin *multicolumn.js* can be found in `examples/plotters/`and not in `plugins`.

```
system.file('examples/plotters/multicolumn.js', package = 'dygraphs')
```

Comment: Apologies - originally you would be correct, but I am using it regularly now so on my local setup I moved it to where the other plugins are located

Comment: Anyhow, when I use it the way I wrote, It works fine with your color codes. And even if I move it to the plugins folder as well, your original code works.

Comment: What if you comment out `dyMultiColumn() %>%`? Does it render with your colors?

Comment: I tried changing the path for the plugin in my function back to the default one you posted and I still get the failure to render in colour. So this I guess points to a local setup thing. Maybe some sort of version compatibility issue. Commenting out dyMultiColumn doesn't work either

Comment: I am using `dygraphs_1.1.1.4`.

Comment: Same here it seems. So not that I guess.